# Do I need to base64 encode all request headers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a C# Web API.  Right now i'm working on authentication.  Each request will be done over SSL and requires the user to make requests over SSL.

What I am wondering is if I need to have the user send Base64 Encoded strings when requesting data or authenticating.  It would go something like this.

Login Method Controller :

```
Public bool Login (User user)
```

Where User consists of :

{"Username":"chris", "Password":"doggie"}

In this case, would it always be best to Base64 Encode chis and doggie in the request header? Or is that not necessary? And do I need to send base 64 encoded strings in all my requests?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of security as long as you are using SSL, this doesn't really make any difference.

But if all requests will require sending the username and password then it would make more sense to *abstract* this information into an `Authorization` header in order to separate it from the actual request payload.

If you decide to use Basic Authentication then you need to send the username and password as Base64 encoded string in the Authorization header. In this example here's how the Authorization header might look like:

```
Authorization: Basic Y2hyaXM6ZG9nZ2ll
```

I might be mistaken but by reading your question I get the feeling that you think that Base64 actually protects the username and password which is wrong. Base64 is reversible, so it is by no means used for any security. It's just a convenient way to send properly encoded binary data in an HTTP request.

Comment: In my understanding, Base64Encoding isn't for security purposes, its for transferring data purposes? Its basically so that there isn't any characters in the request that HTTP can't handle?

Comment: Your understanding is perfectly correct. But if you use a JSON serializer to properly encode your JSON request payload you don't need any Base64. You could more than safely send properly encoded JSON strings in the request body without violating or breaking the protocol.

Comment: Ok sweet.  What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a Web Api for User Management and Authentication.  So for logging in it would be a POST to /api/Account/Login.  The extent of my end that I will be writing is receiving the Post requests and interpreting them.  I already require SSL and will just assume that the Json sent in the request is properly encoded.